# Prove that $\liminf (-a_n) = -\limsup (a_n)$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

> Prove that $\liminf (-a_n) = -\limsup (a_n)$.

by $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ I mean the limit supremum and limit infimum of a sequence $a_n$.

do you guys have any hints?

Comment: Have you tried using the definition of lim inf and lim sup?

Comment: your'e right, I deleted the example.

Comment: $-\liminf (-a_n)=-\lim_{n\to\infty} \inf_{m \geq n} (-a_m) = \lim_{n\to\infty} - \inf_{m\geq n} (-a_m) = \lim_{n \to\infty} \sup_{m \geq n} -(-a_m) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{m \geq n} (a_m) = \limsup (a_n)$. The only step that really needs justification is switching from the $\inf$ to the $\sup$. Can you justify that step?

Comment: @Justpassingby what do you mean by using the definition? the definition I know is that lim sup is the supremum of the partial limits set of a sequence $a_n$ and for lim inf a similar definition, did u mean something else?

Comment: @F1sargyan Working from the definitions is essentially what I did in my comment.

Comment: Lim sup is the *infimum* of a set of suprema, and lim inf is the supremum of a set of infima.

Comment: @kccu I didn't get why did u have to use $m \ge n$ every time and thought about justifying that step u talked about but its not that intuitive.

Comment: @F1sargyan I'm having trouble understanding your comment. The $m \geq n$ appears because that is in the definition of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$. I don't think there's any way you can prove this without using the definitions of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ or relying on more sophisticated results.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded. 
You want to show
$$
\sup_m\inf_{n\geq m}(-a_n)=-\inf_m\sup_{n\geq m}(a_n)\tag{*}
$$

Show first that for any bounded (real) sequence $(b_n)$:
$$
\sup_n (-b_n)=-\inf_n b_n\tag{**}
$$
Now use (**) to show (*).

Comment: what do you mean by sup inf?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior